# InnoDB: SHOW ENGINE STATUS truncating query in deadlock section

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, innodb

Recently I've been having problems troubleshooting deadlocks because the engine log is not displaying the full queries involved. Hibernate generates some pretty long queries, and it seems in the two cases I've been concerned about, InnoDB is limiting itself to 1024 characters when printing the thread information (the line starting with "MySQL thread id...") and the queries themselves (select * from...).

While looking into this, I found a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7819) complaining about the same issue which had an associated [patch](http://lists.mysql.com/internals/28212) that should allow us to fix this issue. However, I'm told that there is no DB variable by the name max_query_len in either 5.0 or 5.1. This is strange to me, as the old limit was 300 characters (which I am seeing more than) but it does not seem to actually be configurable. My question is what actually happened with this - is there a later patch I'm not seeing that changed the fix? 5.0.12's changelog does indeed suggest that the issue was fixed:

```
"SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS now can display longer query strings. (Bug #7819)"
```

but it doesn't seem to me that it actually is. The oldest version we might possibly have had running when the deadlock happened is 5.0.56, so we should at least have the 5.0.12 fix - we do have newer versions running, though, so later versions that might have overwritten the fix for the truncated queries could have been applied. Is anyone aware of what's happened here to cause the limit on what it prints to be lowered again?

Comment: Suggest you create a new bug in bugs.mysql.com .  Reference 7819.  Add the bug number to this thread.

Comment: Bug created here - [bug 80927](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80927).